# Function Calls for Dynamically Loaded Content

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

I have a PHP file that serves up some HTML populated from a MySQL database and is loaded into the DOM. This data is loaded via jQuery *load()* method into the #navContent divide of the HTML document. This functions as planed.

At the very-bottom of the HTML doc, I have a click function that targets the *#navItem* div (*see the first echo line of the php file*) that was dynamically loaded into the DOM but this does not fire.  I know the *#navItem* tag ID is there because my CSS styles it correctly.

What do I have wrong? For now, I just want all the divides that were dynamically created into the *#navContent* div to click thru to a URL.

I am a newB and just learning jQuery so corrected code would be very helpful.  Thnx

In the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    . . .
    var ajaxLoader = '';
    var dns = 'http://www.someURL';
    var navContent = '/folder/my_list.php';
    var bodyContent = '/folder/index.php/somestuff #content';

        $(document).ready(
        function() {
            loadPage(dns + navContent, "navContent");
            loadPage(dns + bodyContent, "bodyContent")
        });
    . . .
    </script>
    . . .
</head>
<body>
    . . .
    <div id="navPanel">

            <div id="navHeader">
                <img src="images/ic_return.png" style="float: left;"/>
                <img  id="listSortBtn" src="images/ic_list_sort.png" style="float: right;"/>
                <h4 id="navHeaderTitle"></h4>
            </div>

            <div id="navScrollContainer" class="navContentPosition">
                <div id="navContent">NAVIGATION CONTENT GETS DUMPED IN HERE</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    . . .
</body>
<!-- ================ Functions ===================================== -->
<!-- **************************************************************** -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    /* --------------- Handle Pg Loading ----------------- */
    function loadPage(url, pageName) {
        $("#" + pageName).load(url, function(response){
            $('#navHeaderTitle').text($(response).attr('title'));
    //          transition("#" + pageName, "fade", false);
        });
    };

    /* ------------- Click Handler for the Nav Items------ */
    $("#navItem").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = 'http://www.google.com';
        var pageName = 'navContent';
        loadPage(url, pageName);
    });
    . . .
</script>
</html>
```

Served PHP File:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pw");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("andaero", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_list");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div id='navItem' title='My Nav Title'>";
echo "<h1>" . $row['label'] . "</h1>";
echo "<h2>" . $row['title'] . "</h2>";
echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "</p>";
echo "</div>";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize that click method AFTER the DOM has been appended with your custom markup. This is a perfect example of a case where OOP programming would do wonders.

You also didn't load the click method into the doc-ready...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyConstructor()
{
    this.ajaxLoader = '';
    this.dns = 'http://www.someURL';
    this.navContent = '/folder/my_list.php';
    this.bodyContent = '/folder/index.php/somestuff #content';

    this.loadPage = function( url, pageName )
    {
        $("#" + pageName).load(url, function(response){
            $('#navHeaderTitle').text($(response).attr('title'));
        });
        this.toggles();
    }

    this.toggles = function()
    {
            var t = this;
        $("#navItem").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = 'http://www.google.com';
            var pageName = 'navContent';
            t.loadPage(url, pageName);
        });
    }

    /**************************************
    *Init Doc-Ready/Doc-Load methods
    **************************************/
    this.initialize = function()
    {
        this.loadPage( this.dns + this.navContent, "navContent");
        this.loadPage( this.dns + this.bodyContent, "bodyContent");
    }
    this.initialize();
}

$( document ).ready( function(){
    var mc = new MyConstructor();

    //now, you can go ahead and re-run any methods from the mc object :)
    //mc.loadPage( arg, 'ye matey' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thnx, I have tried that before (and tried again now just-in-case), but still nothing. Any other ideas???

Comment: I'll take another look at it shortly. There could be another bug inside of your functions I haven't really looked at.

Comment: Thnx again. I left it in the `function loadPage(url, pageName) {...` at the bottom of the HTML doc for now because I think it should be there

Comment: Okay, strike that. I'm going to assume that this is working properly, as per your first paragraph... So when you load the page, the two instantiations of loadPage() are running properly? You have your content, and the answer I edited isn't firing an event on the items rendered after page ready via the loadPage() function? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Yes, 5.3.8. That would be very helpful cuz I'm learning this on the fly. Thnx

Comment: Your $(document).ready method had some syntax errors, too. I just fixed them in my example.

Comment: Correct, the two loadPages() are loading properly and I have the content and I missed the ; when I pasted the code above.

Comment: Hmmm... I would start using console.log() to make sure everything is in place on the click event. Perhaps even adding a few alert flags to see how far the program runs. In the meantime, I'll build you a little js constructor.

Comment: Okay, so put that new answer edit in one script tag, instead of two. See if that concept runs.

Comment: I decided to re-rite the whole thing - basically using JSON instead but still having issues see this [SO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9932281/742030)